# If malloc() is considered causing "dirty memory", is free() cleaning it up?

Tags: iphone, performance

I've heard rumors that calling malloc leads to so called "dirty memory", which you can see in the VM Tracker instrument.

Now, rumors also say one must try to keep the amount of dirty memory as low as possible. But what they didn't talk much about was how to undirty it again.

Sometimes there's no other option than using malloc(). Heck, I love malloc(). For example when creating audio sources for OpenAL, one must malloc() a lot of data.

So: When my app calls malloc() and free() all over the place, I always believed that's fine. Am I having a huge problem when doing that? Or will free() always "clean it up"? I'm a bit confused because some very big guys at a very big company warned that malloc() must be avoided as much as possible, because of this dirty memory problem.

Maybe someone can un-confuse me about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you malloc and free same size memory blocks multiple times, the memory will be reused instead of accumulating dirty VM pages.  So it's perfectly safe as long as you know the max of all possible fragment sizes ever allocated by your app at any one time, and that keeps your app under the OS kill limit.

Comment: Can you go a bit more into detail what you mean by "So it's perfectly safe as long as you know the max of all possible fragment sizes ever allocated by your app at any one time", especially "possible fragment sizes ever allocated by your app"? So does this imply that using malloc, no matter for how less memory, will dirty pages which may be MUCH bigger actually - making these pages unavailable for further malloc's? So essentially one could end up in a situation where the app didn't request THAT much memory via malloc but got killed anyways by jetsam?

Answer (score 3):

I seriously doubt this is true.  All memory allocation in Cocoa is eventually done via malloc. so sayeth Apple's [Memory Usage Performance Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html).  Quoting from that document:

> Because memory is such a fundamental resource, Mac OS X and iOS both
>   provide several ways to allocate it. Which allocation techniques you
>   use will depend mostly on your needs, but in the end all memory
>   allocations eventually use the malloc library to create the memory.
>   Even Cocoa objects are allocated using the malloc library eventually.

I don't know about your big guys at your big company, but I've known big guys at big companies that didn't know squat.  Just sayin'.  Documentation trumps rumors every time.  :)

Comment: They keep everything top-confidiential. But you know them for sure. Can't name them though. At least: Better not to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what they mean by "dirty" and "clean".  Possibly they are referring to the problem of fragmentation.  Doing lots of allocs and frees can cause fragmentation problems, but it really depends on the usage patterns and block sizes you are allocating.  In general, don't worry about using malloc and free.  If you a real reason to avoid the standard allocator, you can use your own allocator.  Then you just call malloc once for a huge block that you can use as the basis of your custom allocator.

Comment: In iOS, virtual memory pages that have been written to are marked dirty and cannot be paged out.  Accumulate too large a fraction of real DRAM and the OS will kill your app.  malloc() may dirty some pages in the process of clearing them for sandbox security reasons.

Comment: hotpaw2, that was exactly their argumentation. Sort of. Now I remember. So using malloc is very, very evil if you have lots of bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - free() will simply clean it up again.